# How to intercept long press on links in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I want to provide my own action sheet or popover, don't want default system one.

Please notice that:

1. I'm asking about **long press** not **click**.
2. I need to know the URL of the link that is being long pressed.

Comment: @AndreiFilip see my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15603818/1371070

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to provide your own action sheet or popover, first you need to disable the default contextual menu. You can do it with javascript by using the following code, inside `webViewDidFinishLoad`

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
```

Once you disable the default behavior you can create your own custom action sheet/popover.

One possible approach is described in the following link:

[Customize the contextual menu of UIWebView](http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/)

Comment: Is there anyway to intercept the image that was tapped on?